# Can 2 files have "same" "many" "different" types of hash?

Tags: file, sha256, hash-collision

I know that **hash collision** is possible with large number of files. But i want to know if **2** files can share "**many** , **different**" types of hash. 
I have 2 hashes **SHA256** and **BLAKE256** (Both will result in  **different** hashes)

 For example:

 File **A** have **SHA256** hash : jhsj8sd87a89sihd8d78a7... etc.

 And **BLAKE256** : js8us8d8saa621g2h34hg... etc.

 So what is the **probability** that a File **B** will have the same **SHA256** and **BLAKE256** when **hashed**.

 And will chance of collision decreases with more hashes, Say **5**.

 **Note** :
Both the files **A** and **B** have exactly same size but different content.

 I have read on internet about hash collision with 2 hashes. But here is the case of **4** hashes. **2** of File **A** and **2** of file **B**.

 And both types are different, one is **SHA256** and one is **BLAKE256**.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to programming?

Comment: SHA-256 outputs 256 bits and SHA1 will output 160 bits, so they cannot be the same.

Comment: Is the question: "Given that two files compute to the same hash code using hashing-algorithm A, does that mean they are more likely to also compute to the same hash code using hashing-algorithm B?"

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I am asking if given a file A hashes down to a unique BLAKE256 and SHA256. What is the chance that an another file B (with different content) will hash down to the same BLAKE256 and SHA256.

Comment: @Akash my intuition is that the two probabilities are independent of each other, so if there is an 1/N chance of a collision under BLAKE256 and a 1/M chance of a collision under SHA256, then there would be a 1/(N*M) chance of collision under both protocols simultaneously.  I'm not knowledgeable enough about hashing to be certain of my intuition, though.

Comment: Btw this question might get more skilled attention at cs.stackexchange.com, since it seems to be more closely related to the theory of hashing algorithms than to practical programming technique.